# Can I group by full class name my tests on NUnit or MSTest using command line?

Tags: command-line, nunit, mstest

The most of my tests uses database integration with NDbUnit and the isolation mode I use is grouping by them full class name.

Now, I need this config runs on command line 'cause I'll use Jenkins CI.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `nunit-console.exe`, then you can by Category. There is documentation on what you can send to the runner [here (http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.2)](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.2). You will likely want to use the `/include` and `/exclude` flags.

Comment: What's the section? I didn't find it.

Comment: "Specifying Test Categories to Include or Exclude"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the mstest.exe commandline using /test

```
mstest /testcontainer:TestProject1.dll /test:TestProject1.Unittest2
```

This will execute all the tests within the UnitTest2 class.

Comment: Are you referring to using the testlist within the vsmdi file. If so then that will need to be maintained as and when you add/remove classes. The approach provided above does not need vsmdi testlist overheads.

Comment: mstest.exe has no option for *excluding* tests based on classname, only on categories.